# Generate fenced Matrix with m and n integers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to generate a matrix with border 1's and 0's at the core when we give m and n positive integers.

```
Input:
4,5


Output
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I used this code.Is there any other way to get the output

```
import numpy as np
a=np.ones((m,n),dtype="int")
a[1:-1,1:-1]=0
```

Comment: This solution is already pretty good, what is it that you are trying to improve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another similar solution, however I prefer the suggested solution in the question:

```
a=np.zeros((m,n),dtype="int")
a[[0,-1]] = 1
a[:,[0,-1]] = 1
```

Or per @Paul's suggestion in comments:

```
a[::m-1] = a[:,::n-1] = 1
```

***EDIT***: Per OP's comment below:

list of arrays:

```
 a = [x for x in a]
```

array of lists:

```
b = np.empty(m,dtype=object)
b[:] = a.tolist()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will be faster than OP for large enough arrays. To make it even faster: Use plain slicing over fancy indexing `a[::m-1] = a[:,::n-1] = 1`

Comment: But the solution which i used generates a 2D matrix.I need a separate list for each row!!

Comment: @PaulPanzer Great suggestion on slicing. Can you give some insight into why it is faster? besides more number of cells being assigned new values (if that is not the only reason). I liked the OP's solution for readability reasons. However, your suggested one is also equally readable. Thank you

Comment: @Kishan You need a 1-D array of lists (for rows) instead of a 2-D array?

Comment: On top of that at least on linux `zeros` is significantly faster than `ones`. I think it is due to there existing a dedicated system call for allocating zeros (`calloc`, I think) but not for ones.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Great. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @Ehsan - Thanks for the suggestion! yes of course, i need 1D-array of lists.

Comment: @Kishan Please find the edit on the post to address that. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
in_str=input()
in_str=in_str.split(',')
m=int(in_str[0])
n=int(in_str[1])

#make a list with n zeroes
final=[0]*n

#make a matrix of m such lists
final=[list(final) for i in range(m)]
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        if i==0 or j==0 or i==m-1 or j==n-1:
            final[i][j]=1
            
#print in the fashion as shown in Sample output
for i in final:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Please add comments to your answer, or give the variables meaningful names. For example, what is `in_str`?